# Handling package and function names dynamically

Tags: go, model-view-controller

I'm on my first Golang project, which consists of a small router for an MVC structure. Basically, what I hope it does is take the request URL, separate it into chunks, and forward the execution flow to the package and function specified in those chunks, providing some kind of fallback when there is no match for these values in the application .

An alternative would be to map all packages and functions into variables, then look for a match in the contents of those variables, but this is not a dynamic solution.

The alternative I have used in other languages (PHP and JS)  is to reference those names sintatically, in which the language somehow considers the value of the variable instead of considering its literal. Something like: **{packageName}.{functionName}()** . The problem is that I still haven't found any syntactical way to do this in Golang.

Any suggestions?

```
func ParseUrl(request *http.Request) {

    //out of this URL http://www.example.com/controller/method/key=2&anotherKey=3

    var requestedFullURI = request.URL.RequestURI()       // returns '/controller/method?key=2key=2&anotherKey=3'
    controlFlowString, _ := url.Parse(requestedFullURI)
    substrings := strings.Split(controlFlowString.Path, "/")       // returns ["controller","method"]
    
    if len(substrings[1]) > 0 {

        // Here  we'll check if substrings[1] mathes an existing package(controller) name
        // and provide some error return in case it does not

        if len(substrings[2]) > 0 {
            // check if substrings[2] mathes an existing function name(method) inside 
            // the requested package and run it, passing on the control flow
        }else{
            // there's no requested method, we'll just run some fallback
        }
    } else {
        err := errors.New("You have not determined a valid controller.")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}
```

Comment: This is doable, but is considered a pretty advanced technique not to be used lightly. The general approach involves exposing `reflect.typelinks` and `reflect.typesByString` and doing low level magic with those. :-) Simpler people just make their own dispatch maps, with string keys and function/interface values, for example.

Comment: You would be well advised to use a more traditional approach, especially on a first project.

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do this instead of declaring handlers for specific routes? I'm trying to imagine an app where you blindly forward any request via reflection to various packages. You're going to want to use middleware (unless your app has no security, etc.) and other things that depend on the route I would imagine. I would [start here](https://gowebexamples.com/) and not try to reinvent the wheel without understanding very precisely what the wheel is doing first.

Comment: @Dean, an application as I have written before can easily grow to 20+ controllers, each one with some other 20+ methods inside. This means 400+ different routes handled by one entry point and it does not seem practical to me to register them all, one by one. Anyway, given the general opinion against this approach I can understand that my failure is less about the implementation on itself, and more about the way applications and built and problems are solved with Go. I am trying to solve the problem in an inappropriate manner. And I can foresee already a long, painful road ahead. Thanks, guys.

Comment: @Rui I hear what you're saying. But you are almost certainly going to want to have security for certain routes that is handled by middleware. Also, let's say you have 500 routes. That's 500 (give or take) lines of code to define them all. When compared to how much code is in the implementation details of 500 routes, I think you'll find it's not a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You can still solve this in half dynamic manner. Define your handlers as methods of empty struct and register just that struct. This will greatly reduce amount of registrations you have to do and your code will be more explicit and readable. For example:

```golang
handler.register(MyStruct{}) // the implementation is for another question
```

Following code shows all that's needed to make all methods of `MyStruct` accessible by name. Now with some effort and help of reflect package you can support the routing like `MyStruct/SomeMethod`. You can even define struct with some fields witch can serve as branches so even `MaStruct/NestedStruct/SomeMethod` is possible to do.

### dont do this please

Your idea may sound like a good one but believe me its not. Its lot better to use framework like [go-chi](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) that is more flexible and readable then doing some reflect madness that no one will understand. Not to mention that traversing type trees in go was newer the fast task. Your routes should not be defined by names of structures in your backend. When you commit into this you will end up with strangely named routes that use PascalCase instead of something-like-this.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is very typical of PHP and JavaScript, and completely inappropriate to Go. PHP and JavaScript are dynamic, interpreted languages. Go is a static, compiled language. Rather than trying to apply idioms which do not fit, I'd recommend looking for ways to achieve the same *goals* using implementations more suitable to the language at hand.

In this case, I think the closest you get to what you're describing while still maintaining reasonable code would be to use a handler registry as you described, but register to it automatically in [package `init()` functions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization). Each `init` function will be called once, at startup, giving the package an opportunity to initialize variables and register things like handlers and drivers. When you see things like database driver packages that need to be imported even though they're not referenced, `init` functions are why: importing the package gives it the chance to register the driver. The `expvar` package even does this to register an HTTP handler.

You can do the same thing with your handlers, giving each package an `init` function that registers the handler(s) for that package along with their routes. While this isn't "dynamic", being dynamic has zero value here - the code can't change after it's compiled, which means that all you get from being dynamic is slower execution. If the "dynamic" routes change, you'd have to recompile and restart anyway.